# How to style the installer?

Tags: air, installation

I'm developing an AIR app for a client, and they've had a gfx designer edit some graphics for the app.

He's also asked that the installer be changed from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

<sup>(ignore the XP window style)</sup>

Is that possible? I haven't found anything relevant from Googling or searching SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible, the installation of `.air` packages is handled by the AIR runtime, you cannot change its appearance. Native packages might be standalone installers themselfs, not 100% sure, but their style also cannot be changed.

If you want custom styles, then you have to package your app as a captive runtime application and create your very own installer for it.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/customize-setup-for-AIR-app-with-captive-runtime.html

Comment: I'm actually already using a native package already, in order to be able to use `NativeProcess`es; but I'm targetting namespace v2.0 and it seems like to be able to use `-target bundle` with `adt`, it requires at least v3.0. So it's a no-go for us! Thanks for your answer!