# Custom Adobe AIR (badge) Installation Process

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I have a silly question.
Is there any way to make a custom adobe air application installer?

Now, after I click on the badge "install" button (on the web site), air app starts installation process in 4 steps (3 mouse clicks):

1. First, I have 3 buttons ("open", "save" and "cancel"), I click on "open";
2. Then I have 2 buttons ("install", "cancel"), and I have to click on "install";
3. After that, I have options to change installation directory location, add shortcut icon on the desktop, and 2 buttons again ("continue" and "cancel"), I have to click on "continue";
4. And finally, installation begins.

Is there any way to avoid some steps here (e.g. second step), or maybe to disable some buttons (like "save" button in the first step, or "add shortcut icon on my desktop" in the third)?

If it's not possible, is there any way to create custom air app installer?

Thanks

P.S. I don't have problem with these 3 mouse clicks during installation, but my clients consider that "I have" 1 extra click.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815533/how-to-style-the-installer. Not quite the same question, but the answer will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below links for more clarity

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/customize-setup-for-AIR-app-with-captive-runtime.html

If you want custom badge style, you have to pack your app as captive runtime and create your own installer.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at the links, and it could be a solution. :)
If I understood well, WiX creates an .exe (for Win) or .dmg (for Mac) installation file, is it possible to run installation process over a badge in that case?

Anyway, I'll try this, thanks a lot. :)